# What does the number of "all time users" of a chatroom exactly mean?

Tags: support, chat

When [info about a chatroom](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) is shown, it contains two numbers. The tooltip says that one of the numbers represent *all time users* and the other one is for *all time messages*.

[image: example]

What exactly does the number of all time users mean? Which users are counted in this statistics?

I have noticed in [a room which has rather low activity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9560/representation-theory), that there are several users who posted at least one message in that room. (Maybe some or all of them posted exactly one message - I did not check the whole transcript of the room.) But the number shown in the room info is much lower. Is there a minimal number of messages that users must post before they are counted towards this number or some other criteria?

Comment: The room where I have noticed this was [this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9560/representation-theory). At the moment it says *2 all time users*. Already in first few days I see for users, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9560/2013/7/8) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9560/2013/7/15). [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9560/2013/11/2) you can see two more users posting at least one message in that room.

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for the answer myself.  I analyzed [your example room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9560/representation-theory) today (17 Apr 2022) where it says that "all time users" = 2.  Besides the room owner (Tobias, with >10 messages), the only other person posting more than 2 messages is Martin Sleziak (18 messages).  The Masked and Kan posted 2 each, the other 3 users posted 1 each.  **So it appears that a user with 2 messages or below is not counted**.

I compared with [another room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/135456/discussion-on-answer-by-gratefuldisciple-how-is-young-earth-creationism-theologi) which has "all time users" = 2 but the total number of posters are 7.  Four users posted 1 comment each, 1 user posted 2 messages, 1 user posted 3 messages, and 1 user posted >5 messages.

**Therefore, it seems that a user needs to post a minimum of 3 messages to be counted.**

Comment: That is just a "best guess", and need more research to verify it. Also, chat room has "messages" not "comments". This is a comment. Those are two very different things in SE.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Thanks for the correction.  But my empirical observation has been validated by quite a number of other frozen rooms, so I'm quite confident that's the formula.  If you could find an official source, that would be great.

Comment: Yeah, most of those questions are left in the dark without any official response, ever, so all we have are best guesses, which are many times correct.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple -- could you clarify whether or not you think the criteria for freezing rooms (which appears to be "A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users." -- from https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention" is based on that "all time user" number, or on the *actual* total number of people who have ever posted?)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple -- OK, I found a test case that shows it is the latter.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/133835 .  12 users if I counted right, 21 posts, but only one user posted more than 2 times, so the little number on the left in the box is only "1".  Yet the room was only "frozen", not "deleted".

Comment: @GratefulDisciple -- the first of my comments above was supposed to read "... the criteria for *keeping* rooms, i.e. for only *freezing* rather than *deleting*, at such time as they are judged to have become inactive (which appears to be ..." But the question now seems to have been answered by the following comment.