# Who can see "deleted" chat rooms? What is the difference between a "frozen" and a "deleted" room?

Tags: support, chat

I have a series of questions about "deleted" chat rooms.  Likely answers might include: a) Anyone, whether logged in or not.  b) Anyone logged in as an *[Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour)* (ASE) member.  c) The creator of the room plus any other past participants d) Anyone with enough rep (10,000) to see deleted questions and answers that are not their own, plus anyone else who can see all deleted answers and questions (e.g. moderators and staff). e) Other criteria (please explain)

Answers might include combinations of above options (e.g. c + d)

1. Who can see the names of deleted chat rooms, if they go to the chat room index (https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=aviation.stackexchange.com) and click on the "show frozen/deleted rooms" tab?
2. Who can actually see the chat content of those rooms, navigating via the above method?
3. Who can see the chat content of those rooms, if provided with the correct URL for the room itself (e.g.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44936/2016/9/5)

Basically I'm trying to fully understand what is the difference between a "frozen" and a "deleted" room.

This is not a proposed change in policy to be voted on, but it might possibly lead to one.

Two more questions—

4. Do any of the chat rooms that are automatically created when a user accepts the "let us continue this conversation in chat" option (or whatever the exact wording is) ever get "deleted"?
5. With those chat rooms (described in 4), do the comments that are automatically copied over into the room when it is created, count as chat posts toward the criteria that are used to determine when the room will be "deleted" (if that ever happens)?  (The criteria for not "deleting" appear to be "A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users."—from https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention.)

Assume access is from a computer, not a phone, if it matters.  Assume "mobile" option is *not* selected—if you see the chat room index as a single vertical list of entries of three lines each, rather than an array of square boxes, then you are in the "mobile" mode and you need to hit the "sandwich" box in the upper left corner and select "full site" from the menu that drops down.  Questions *may* be answerable from "mobile" mode too, but I'm not certain that all the answers would be the same.)

(***Please note*** that when entering a "deleted" room it often opens to a basically blank page in which case you have to click the tab to go back to previous messages; don't mistake that for not being able to see any of the chat posts.)

Any ASE member with rep ***less than*** 10,000 (and who therefore does not have general privileges to see deleted questions and answers),  might be able to answer most of of these questions.  For example, when you go to the chat room index page (https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=created&nohide=true&host=aviation.stackexchange.com) and click on the "show frozen/deleted rooms" tab, do you see a room (on the first page, if sorted by "active") titled "A room to discuss "Late..."?  That is a deleted room.  If you can see it, that narrows the answer to 1) down to options a or b.  If you can't see it, *or if the button on the lower right corner says only "show (or hide) frozen rooms" rather than "show (or hide) frozen/deleted rooms"*, then options a and b are eliminated.  Similarly for questions 2 and 3.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277010/will-frozen-chat-rooms-be-deleted

Comment: Your avatar is broken because you changed something in your Google account, can you please manually change the avatar?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars -- I believe I never had one.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars -- I'll try to figure out how to get one.

Comment: You can change it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), you should see your broken avatar (or maybe for you it's not broken in case it's defined as Private in your account) and "Change picture" link on it.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure your avatar was fine when you posted this question, I really don't like broken images and notice them quickly.

Answer (score 3):

**The questions now appears to have been fully answered.**

Re questions 1,2, and 3:

***[This Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321067/413377) states that "deleted" chat rooms are visible to those with 10,000 reputation points.***

It's not completely clear what reputation points are "transferrable" from other SE sites to ASE for this purpose: having this reputation, I find that I can see "deleted" chat rooms on other SE sites that I'm not a member of (for example [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)).  However I can only see "frozen" rooms, not "deleted" rooms, here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms.

At any rate, for someone who joined *only* ASE, the criteria to see "deleted" chat rooms would be to have earned 10,000 reputation points on Aviation SE.

Re question 4:

Here are examples of rooms that appear to have been started with posts moved from comment discussions, when a participant accepted the "automatically continue this conversation in chat" option, that currently *are* "deleted".  You can also navigate from these rooms to the original questions or answers from where the comments were copied.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21817/2015/3/10 (2 participants and 6 posts total, at least 3 of which were also comments to the answer.)

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19649/discussion-between-radu094-and-rbp  (2 participants and 9 posts total, at least 7 of which were also comments to the answer.)

**So the answer to question 4 is "yes".**

Re question 5:

Scrolling back through all 27 pages of past chat rooms, I see that there are *no* examples of "deleted" rooms containing more than 15 messages, according to the number in the lower right hand corner of the question box, except for a few rooms that only had a single user ever post to them.  And it's clear that the system "does" count the messages that are copied over from the comment discussion as part of the count for that number in the lower right hand corner of the question box.  Therefore it's clear that these copied messages *are* also counted toward the criteria of not "deleting" the chat room if there are more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

**So the answer to question 5 is "yes".**

Supplemental content:

I had a related question re why the "all time users" number in the lower-left corner of the chat room box was sometimes less than the actual number of people who ever posted, and whether the actual number or the "all time users" statistic was used to calculate whether the question met the criteria for not being deleted (more than 15 messages, by at least 2 users.) The answer is that it's the actual number that's used, not the statistic.  As shown by [this case](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133835/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-sowsun-do-airline-pilots-really-put-on-an-oxygen-ma) which had 12 users, 21 posts, but only one user posted more than 2 times, so the "all time users" statistic shown on the little number in the lower left corner of the chat room box is only "1". Yet the room was only "frozen", not "deleted".

For more about the "active users" statistic and how it is calculated, see the related question [What does the number of "all time users" of a chatroom exactly mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208571/what-does-the-number-of-all-time-users-of-a-chatroom-exactly-mean).

Comment: Re which rep points are transferrable from which sites: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87773/413377 , https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257816/413377 -- relates to being able to chat, but prob also relates to being able to see deleted chat rooms.